# Deploy an office add-in to office 365

Tags: visual-studio, office365, office365-apps

Adding an office add-in to an office 365 subscription should be fairlly easy, you package the add-in, upload the xml-file; done.

[Here is a guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-Admin-Center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f)

I publish it to my azure website, I get the xml file, then I go to upload it in the admin center.

However I cannot find any of these options in my admin center, there is no "**Add an office add-in**" option to go to. Is this out-dated? How can I do this?

EDIT: It seems that some things have been changed in the admin center in the past few months (found more ppl with this problem, but no answer), but have they really removed this feature completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so I'm clear are you saying you don't see the "Services and Add-Ins" option under Settings in Admin Center? This functionality is currently available only on English language tenants. We are working hard to get this functionality rolled out worldwide but for now there is this restriction

Thanks
Phil